# Cordova camera plugin image gets flipped with front camera

Tags: android, ios, cordova, camera, ionic-framework

I'm using the cordova camera plugin for an app i'm working on and i'm wondering if anyone has found a way to stop the image from flipping on the front facing camera. for example if you point in on the left side of the camera it will flip to the right hand side on the final image.

```
$scope.takePhoto = function() {
    //take picture with the camera
    Camera.getPicture({
        quality: 50,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
        correctOrientation: true,
        destinationType: 0,
        encodingType: 0
    }).then(function(imageData) {
        console.log("Success")
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("error")
    });
};
```

added code with camera settings incase its useful.

Comment: Curious - isn't that how it is supposed to work? If you use your device camera and take a picture of yourself, does it end up the same way?

Comment: Not for me it looks normal before its taken. Then when i take the picture it shows flipped rather than the way it was on the screen. I tested to see how it works on other apps like snapchat and it does not do this.

Comment: Ok... so I can confirm this. Technically it is still... correct. I pointed at my left shoulder and the image had me still pointing at my left shoulder. But let me see if I can correct this.

Comment: Actually - this is what I see on iOS. I pointed at my left shoulder. The image *preview* showed the reverse but the *saved* picture was just like Cordova. So it is only the *preview* in the Camera app that is showing it, not the saved file. Make sense?

Comment: The image is showing the same for me once saved as it is on the preview. Im on android though so this may be why it's different. What do you mean by 'the saved picture was just like Cordova' don't understand.

Comment: just found someone with a similar issue on google groups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/fk5fPFhGCtc

Comment: What I meant is - what I saw in Cordova matched what I saw in the Photo Gallery. In iOS, it is flipped on "initial take", but back to what Cordova shows in the Photo Gallery.

Comment: Ok got you now just wanted to confirm. It just stays flipped for me on android.

Comment: Was there any resolution to this issue?

Comment: @ShaneGadsby I looked for a while it seems different devices handle this different ways and that is just the way it works, just built in camera functionality doesn't seem to be a setting you can change easily as far as i am aware.

Answer (score 3):

After searching for a while it turns out there is no sure way to change this within the cordova plugin it mainly depends on your native camera's way of dealing with images most of the phones seems to do this on the front facing camera. The phone reverses the preview picture so you can take it correctly (left is left, etc.), then after the picture is taken, it flips it back the correct way so that text, etc., are not reversed. There is no setting to change this behavior. It just seems most people arent used to seeing themselves that way.

Comment: Kinda sucks, but at least it's consistent

Comment: Yeah I'm sure some that there is plenty of photo editing frameworks for cordova/ionic that allow you to edit things like this, I found most of them were overkill for what i needed though.

some examples i found:
https://github.com/m1is/AviaryCordovaPlugin
https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/

I've not actually tried any out but they may be useful to someone. Im sure adobe has even made one.